# CakePHP 3.0 build a permission menu using Cells

Tags: cakephp, menu, cakephp-3.0

I would like to create a menu in new CakePHP 3.0 and I found that using [cells](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html) might be a good way. So let's say I created *UserMenuCell*

```
class UserMenuCell extends Cell {
    protected $_validCellOptions = [];

    public function display() {
        $menu = [];

        $menu[] = $this ->menu( __('Dashboard'), array( 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'dashboard' ), 'fa-dashboard', [] );

        if( $this -> Auth -> isAuthorized(null, ??? ))
            $menu[] = $this ->menu( __('Barcodes'), array( 'controller' => 'Barcodes', 'action' => 'index' ), 'fa-table', [] );

        $this -> set ( 'menu',  $menu );
    }

    private function menu( $title, $url = [], $icon, $submenu = [] ) {
        return ['title' => $title, 'url' => $url, 'icon' => $icon, 'submenu' => $submenu]; }
}
```

But I want to display *Barcodes* item only when current user is authorized to manage barcodes. How can I do it? I **can't even access $this -> Auth** to get current user.

In my cell's template is everything OK. I just need to create this nested array for menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [problem is solved](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/4355#issuecomment-53161795):

I can make controller to have static method for example static public function `_isAuthorized($user, $request)` which would handle the authorization logic (so every controller controls only its own permissions).

And then I can just call from anywhere for example `PostsController::_isAuthorized($user, ['action' => 'add'])`. This should solve all problems I guess.
Also good point is to pass `$this -> Auth -> user()` into view, so it can be used in **Cells** (through parameter).

**src/Controller/AppController.php**

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    $this -> set('user', $this -> Auth -> user());
}
```

**src/View/Cell/MenuCell.php**

```
use App\Controller\PostsController; // Don't forget to use namespace of your Controller

class MenuCell extends Cell {
    public function display($user) {
        $menu = [];
        if (PostsController::_isAuthorized($user, ['action' => 'add'])) // In that method you must handle authorization
            $menu[] = ['title' => 'Add post', 'url' => array('controller' => 'Posts', 'action' => 'add')];
       $this -> set ('menu', $menu); // Handle this in Template/Cell/Menu/display.ctp
    }
}
```

**src/Template/Cell/Menu/display.ctp** - just to show how to render menu

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($menu as $item) {
        echo '<li>' . $this -> Html -> link ($item['title'], $item['url']);
    } ?>
</ul>
```

**src/Template/Layout/default.ctp** - render menu in main layout

```
<?= $this -> cell('Menu', array($user)) /* This is the user passed from beforeFilter */ ?>
```

Then you can play with `isAuthorized` methods. For example you can edit your `AppController`. Always when *CakePHP* calls `isAuthorized` function it will be redirected to `YourNameController::_isAuthorized()` static method (if exists).

**src/Controller/AppController.php**

```
public function isAuthorized( $user ) {
    $childClass = get_called_class();

    if(method_exists($childClass, '_isAuthorized'))
        return $childClass::_isAuthorized($user, $this -> request);

    return static::_isAuthorized($user, $request);
}

static public function _isAuthorized($user, $request)
{
    if ($user['role'] == 'admin')
        return true;

    return false; // By default deny any unwanted access
}
```

This is an example of your controller. You can specify only static `_isAuthorized($user, $request)` method, because for purposes of *CakePHP* default behavior it will be called from `AppController::isAuthorized` (see code above).

**src/Controller/PostController.php**

```
static public function _isAuthorized($user, $request)
{
    $action = ($request instanceof Cake\Network\Request) ? $request -> action : $request['action'];

    if($action == 'add' && $user['role'] == 'CanAddPosts')
        return true;

    return parent::_isAuthorized($user, $request);
}
```

As you can see I made $request to accept an **array** or **Cake\Network\Request** object. That's because *CakePHP* call it with *Request* object but when I call it I don't need to create this object, since my parameters are easy (see code above *MenuCell.php*).

Of course you can now do more complex logic like user can have more roles separated by comma and you can [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) this and check if user has permission by [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).
Now it's really up to you what is your logic behind permissions. Every controller can handle it's own permission managing while you can always access these permissions with every user and every page request.

Comment: I don't really like this solution since you're passing an authorization structure through a view, which is bad practice, see this discussion: [link](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/3929). The suggestions below seem better since you're keeping the knowledge of Auth at the cell's "controller" level and only exposing necessary data to the view.

Comment: @RogerKaplan What authorization structure is passed to view? In view I only ask if "user has permission to see something". I ask it controller using `PostsController::_isAuthorized` but isn't this similar to Rails? They have cancan gem where in the view you do something like `can? :show, User`. From the link you've posted what exact piece of code do you mean?

Comment: In the first code segment you are passing `$this->Auth->user()` which is the main auth structure, into all views via the view variable $user. The fact that you keep the go/no go logic in a controller is irrelevant if you're passing the secrets to the view, just to have the view pass them back. Access to Auth from views was specifically removed from cake3 and I saw some dialog with Mark Story defending that design decision (I forget where).

Answer (score 1):

According to Cookbook, the session is available from within Cells.

```
class UsermenuCell extends Cell
{
    public function display()
    {
        var_dump($this->request->session()->read('Auth'));
    }
}
```

Like this you could read the needed informations in your cell display function.

Comment: As per my comment to the accepted answer, I think this is a cleaner approach as it doesn't require passing the Auth structure (which has hashed pw...) through the view.

Answer (score 0):

and if you pass the session variable?

```
<?= $this->cell('userMenu', $this->Session->read('Auth')); ?>
```